# AdSense doesn't support web app. Alternatives ad providers to monetize?

Tags: ads, adsense, banner-ads

I'm building a web app for a client that has asked that I use AdSense to display banner ads, but I get the following error when I request approval:

> Valuable Inventory: No content.
> We do not allow monetization where there is no content.

From [what I've seen on other forums](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/45716771?hl=en&msgid=45719476), it appears that AdSense will simply not approve web apps like this one (very little text, and what text does show on some pages is javascript-generated or requires clicks to view, so crawlers probably won't see it). I'm currently looking for alternative ad providers to pitch to this client, but I'm having a tough time finding one that integrates with browser web apps.

Does anyone have any similar experience / suggestions for ad providers? The app is a Google Maps instance overlaid with user generated content, primarily to be used on mobile (native iOS and Android apps to come after deployment on browser).